# com.example package name not allowed in Google Play

Tags: android

I'm new to android application development. I'm creating simple android application.
Export the android application and give the package name as `AndroidManifestfile` packagename as

```
 com.example.zingyminds.apk
```

Now I got the apk file and upload to the google play at that time I got the below error message please anyone help me.

**The package name of your apk may not begin with any of the following values: `[com.android, com.google, android, com.example]`**

Comment: You have already answered your question in the last paragraph. and please dont include signatures to your post. There are already very beautifull signatures of you in the bottom right corner of your post(the rectangle mentioning your name).

Comment: @ArulKumar Please see my answer, it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 10):

Packages are typically named using the following convention:

```
[org/com].[company].[product].[component]
```

By convention, package names should not contain capitals.

Google Play identifies all the applications on the basis of their package name, so some of the names are reserved for the default applications of the android, like you have mentioned in the last paragraph,

```
[com.android, com.google, android, com.example]
```

so, these package name are discouraged and you should use the upper conventions for describing the package name, something like this,

```
com.zingyminds.apk
```

Answer (score 8):

Rename your package name **com.example.zingyminds.apk** to **com.zingyminds.apk**

Google Play doesn't care about the filename of your application. It cares
about the package name defined in the manifest.

Answer (score 2):

If you observe properly, the fourth value in error message is 'com.example' which is same as starting of your package com.example.zingyminds... Rename your package to something else which is not listed in the message, it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Packages are typically named using the following convention:

```
[com.android, com.google, android, com.example]
```

so, these package name are discouraged and you should use the upper conventions for describing the package name, something like this,

if you want to mention example in your package name, try this

```
com.zingyminds.example.apk
```

Comment: Why is this and [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14050710/4256973) from Sahil Mahajan Mj so similar? Were they duplicated from some official docs?